# How to send push notification from expo at 8am Europe/Paris?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to implement a push notification every morning at 8am Europe/Paris using expo sdk.

In [their example](https://snack.expo.io/MIGrUKOtW), the push notification seems to be triggered from the client.

This example can also be found in [expo notification push system documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/sdk/notifications/).

What I need to implement is a notification every day at 8 am Europe/Paris, I believe the trigger must be send from the server.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that you have to implement it in your backend.

Look at the [doc](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/sending-notifications/)